# Quiz or exam on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, sharepoint-addin, design

Is there any way to create/add a quiz on SharePoint 2010 just using MS SharePoint designer and InfoPath?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried the out of the box Survey list? It has options so entries can only be seen by the submitter and options to allow editting of own items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Creating a Quiz Web application using SharePoint designer**
>   We mostly use the very powerful Data View Web Part (DVWP) to build our application and  we will cover some great ways of manipulating list data, such as:
>
> - Passing parameters  from one web page to another via a
>     query string
> - Passing  values  from one web part to another
> - Removing the (usually mandatory) Title field from  list forms and
>     views
> - Using useful system variables (such as the logged in user and current
>     date)
> - Pre-loading form fields with values
> - Creating a persistent session identifier to link multiple list items
> - Creating custom forms and passing multiple parameters in a redirected
>     form
> - Manipulation of the HTML presentation using XSLT

Read complete [Post here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/14/creating-a-quiz-web-application-using-sharepoint-designer.aspx), there are total 5 parts of this.